# Explanation of limitations of mean deviation?

Tags: statistics

My [textbook (section 15.4.3 page 361)](https://ncert.nic.in/textbook/pdf/kemh115.pdf) says this

> In a series, where the degree of variability is very high, the median is not a representative central tendency. Thus, the mean deviation about median calculated for such series can not be fully relied.
>
> The sum of the deviations from the mean (minus signs ignored) is more than the sum of the deviations from median. Therefore, the mean deviation about the mean is not very scientific. Thus, in many cases, mean deviation may give unsatisfactory results.

Why are deviations from the median always less than those about the mean? And how can we conclude that the mean deviation about the mean is not very scientific, from this fact? I tried searching the internet, but none of them explain these disadvantages of mean deviation over standard deviation. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2):

Take the derivative of the mean absolute distance from a number $m$ with respect to $m$. You should find that it is the mean of $\operatorname{sign}(x-m)$*. This is zero provided there is equal probability to be less than $m$ and greater than $m$, so $m$ is a median. It can happen that there are no such numbers (e.g. if $P(X=0)=0.6,P(X=1)=0.4$), in which case you need to be a bit more careful in identifying the minimizer, but there still is at least one and we still call it a median.

By contrast, the mean $\mu$ minimizes the mean of $(x-\mu)^2$, which means this is really the natural measure of fluctuations when your "center" is the mean.

* There is some caution to be taken here in the case when $x=m$ with positive probability.

Comment: Could you explain why always mean deviation about mean is greater than or equal to that of median

Comment: @Raghav It isn't *always* so; sometimes the mean is a median, in which case the mean deviation about the mean is the same as the mean deviation about a median. For example, the normal distribution and Bernoulli(1/2) distribution have the same mean and median. But if the mean is not a median, then the derivative of the mean absolute distance with respect to $m$ at $m=\mu$ is nonzero, and so you can reduce it by going to a different value of $m$.

Comment: @Raghav Do you see why the mean of $\operatorname{sign}(x-m)$ is zero if and only if there is equal probability to be less than $m$ and greater than $m$? That and the derivative calculation itself are the key points here.